# Searching for an element in an image with python

Tags: python, image-processing

It is necessary to find all the squares in the image and get their coordinates in the form of an array. Is there a way to do this without using AI ?

[image]

Comment: It is not clear from the image which ones should be extracted. Also sample output co-ordinates should be provided in the post.

Comment: @НиколайНарушев do you mean the black squares (the small ones)? if they have always the same size you can use this [tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/02/08/opencv-shape-detection)

Comment: make a GUI, click on the things, collect the coordinates.